# what's the scenario of stealing information with XSS on a POST request

Tags: security, post, xss

I understand the scenario of stealing information with XSS on a **GET** post as below workflow:

1. Hacker identifies a page from a web application with vulnerability of being XSS injected through query string parameters.
2. Hacker composes a url with XSS injected query string appended.
3. Hacker sends the url to a victim, for example, by email.
4. Victim receives the mail and clicks on the url (suppose the victim has less knowledge of security).
5. The opened web page has XSS injected, any further action on the page could result in a security issue.

This is possible because clicking on the url link will open the web page in GET mode. So, I am wondering if the page is XSS vulnerable for **POST** request, will it be a security issue? I could not figure out a "reasonable" attack workflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, I am wondering if the page is XSS vulnerable for POST request, will it be a security issue?

Of course it would be. Why should the *method* via which external code is embedded matter at all? *That* it does happen is the problem, not *how*.

> I could not figure out a "reasonable" attack workflow.

Consider a simple HTML form, that gets pre-populated with the previous user input after a failed server-side validation.

If this pre-popuplating allows XSS (basically meaning, escaping all data before outputting it in an HTML context was neglected) – then I could easily set up a form in my own page, have its `action` attribute point to your form handling address, and pass any data I like via hidden fields – and have to user send that data to your server via a simple submit button, that is maybe formated to look just like a normal link, and only saying “click here to go to example.com”. The user expects that to just ”normally” open a page like any other link – but in reality it send values that triggers displaying the form with pre-populated fields again.

Et voilà, XSS attack successfully performed.

(All that under the premise that the target site does not have additional security against “foreign” form data in place.)

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! I mean the starting page is a page only accepts POST request, say my_post_request.aspx. from my understanding, I need prepare a complete post request with XSS string embedded and send it to server, then server response me a page with XSS action included which has security issue. But I don't understand how does this happen because if I send the page URL (my_post_request.aspx) to others, and others' click action is a GET action rather than desired POST action.

Comment: XSS is not only about sending an URL to another person – as I said in my example, I could build a fake form using hidden fields for the data into my own page, and have you submit that by a button with a misleading description.

Comment: OK, then I understand I should handle security issues on POST requests also.

Answer (score 2):

The attacker could also build a 'data:' URL containing an auto-submitting form:

data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+CiAgPGJvZHkgb25sb2FkPSJkb2N1bWVudC5mb3Jtc1swXS5zdWJtaXQoKSI+CiAgICA8Zm9ybSBtZXRob2Q9InBvc3QiIGFjdGlvbj0iaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdCI+CiAgICAgIDxpbnB1dCB0eXBlPSJoaWRkZW4iIG5hbWU9ImVybnN0IiB2YWx1ZT0iPHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgnWFNTJyk8L3NjcmlwdD4iPgogICAgPC9mb3JtPgo8L2h0bWw+

which is equivalent to navigating to a page containing this markup:

<html>
  <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
    <form method="post" action="...">
      <input type="hidden" name="ernst" value="<script>alert('XSS')</script>">
    </form>
</html>

Comment: thanks for your answer! could you share me more information what is a data URL? I have no knowledge of that? any reference?

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this exact issue while performing a penetration test for a client.  When reporting, we usually try to show a proof of concept exploit using a GET request as this is much easier.  Remember too that some servers may allow you to change a POST to a GET request.  Some servers will also accept POST parameter values in a URL.  In my most recent experience, the server would only accept a request as a POST with the input entered into the form fields.  The only thing that stopped an XSS attack was the fact that they had Cross Site Request Forgery prevention in place (via ViewState).  So, in this case, it is simply a reflection fault.  Still not good, but not as bad.  You should ALWAYS use both ingress and egress filtering and NEVER trust user-controllable data.